# How to show/hide content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where I would like two buttons which when one is clicked, displays hello, and when the other one is clicked would hide the "hello" message and then display "goodbye". I know this needs to be done in javascript but I am not good with javascript.

Comment: This is extremely basic. If you can't figure this out yourself, you need to read some Javascript tutorials. Otherwise you'll be coming here for every little thing you need to do.

Comment: I know, I tried some javascript but it would display messages, but not hide the previous message. As I said, I have no experience with javascript

Comment: If you want help with your code, you need to post what you tried. Then we can show you what you did wrong, and you'll learn from that. You don't learn much by just copying code someone else wrote.

Comment: Okay, I will in future, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this snippet

```html
<p id="msg"></p>

<button onclick="helloFunction()">Say Hello</button>
<button onclick="byeFunction()">Wave Goodbye</button>

<script>
function helloFunction() {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
  
  function byeFunction() {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Goodbye";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's perfect. Thank you!

Comment: If it solves your problem you should make this as the correct answer.  Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it, one of which would be affecting the visiblity of dom elements which say hello or goodbye, the other method as illustrated below you would actually change the text of a dom object based on which button is pressed

```
<button onClick="javascript:say('Hello');">Say Hi</button>
<button onClick="javascript:say('Goodbye');">Say Goodbye</button>
<div id="TextField"></div>
<script>
    function say(text) {
        var element = document.getElementById("TextField");
        element.innerHTML = text;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

here what you'll need to achieve such a feat.

first create a div or a p tag to hold ur text and two buttons
eg

```
    <div id="container">Hello</div>
    <button id="show">Show</button>
    <button id="hide">Show</button>
```

make sure your div has an id and you buttons too. You use that for reference.

then in your javascript, you can either toggle the display or visibility of the div

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      //Declare variable
     var div = document.getElementById("container");
     var show = document.getElementById("show");
      var hide = document.getElementById("hide");

     //run when windows fully loads
     window.onload = function(){

         //when i click show button
         show.onclick = function(){
                div.style.display = "block";
          }

         //when i click hide button
         hide.onclick = function(){
              div.style.display = "none";
            }

         }

      //That is champ, this is all vanilla javascript. You can also look              into implementing with jquery.
    </script>
```

Comment: why the mark down? inline javascript is really not best practise